# Find and scrape all URLs with specific format using Scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, html

I am using Scrapy to retrieve information about projects on https://www.indiegogo.com. I want to scrape all pages with the url format `www.indiegogo.com/projects/[NameOfProject]`. However, I am not sure how to reach all of those pages during a crawl. I can't find a master page that hardcodes links to all of the `/projects/` pages. All projects seem to be accessible from https://www.indiegogo.com/explore (through visible links and the search function), but I cannot determine the set of links/search queries that would return all pages. My spider code is given below. These start_urls and rules scrape about 6000 pages, but I hear that there should be closer to 10x that many.

About the urls with parameters: The `filter_quick` parameter values used come from the "Trending", "Final Countdown", "New This Week", and "Most Funded" links on the Explore page and obviously miss unpopular and poorly funded projects. There is no max value on the `per_page` url parameter.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
class IndiegogoSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "indiegogo"
allowed_domains = ["indiegogo.com"]
start_urls = [
    "https://www.indiegogo.com/sitemap",
    "https://www.indiegogo.com/explore",
    "http://go.indiegogo.com/blog/category/campaigns-2",
    "https://www.indiegogo.com/explore?filter_browse_balance=true&filter_quick=countdown&per_page=50000",
    "https://www.indiegogo.com/explore?filter_browse_balance=true&filter_quick=new&per_page=50000",
    "https://www.indiegogo.com/explore?filter_browse_balance=true&filter_quick=most_funded&per_page=50000",
    "https://www.indiegogo.com/explore?filter_browse_balance=true&filter_quick=popular_all&per_page=50000"
]
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/explore?'))),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/campaigns-2/'))),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/projects/')), callback='parse_item'),
)
def parse_item(self, response):
    [...]
```

Sidenote: there are other URL formats `www.indiegogo.com/projects/[NameOfProject]/[OtherStuff]` that either redirect to the desired URL format or give 404 errors when I try to load them in the browser.  I am assuming that Scrapy is handling the redirects and blank pages correctly, but would be open to hearing ways to verify this.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have the link to sitemap than it will be faster to let Scrapy fetch pages from there and process them. 
This will work something like below.

> from scrapy.contrib.spiders import SitemapSpider
>
> class MySpider(SitemapSpider):
>
> ```
> sitemap_urls = ['http://www.example.com/robots.txt']
> ```
>
> //**you can set rules for extracting URLs under sitemap_rules.
>
> ```
> sitemap_rules = [
>     ('/shop/', 'parse_shop'),
> ]
> sitemap_follow = ['/sitemap_shops']
>
> def parse_shop(self, response):
>     pass # ... scrape shop here ...
> ```

Comment: The sitemap only directly links to 1000 projects. The following code only scrapes those 1000. I don't see a way to tell it to follow various URLs like for the CrawlSpider to get it to follow links not directly on the sitemap. Am I missing something?

`class IndiegogoSitemapSpider(SitemapSpider):`
    `name = "indiegogo_sitemap"`
    `sitemap_urls = ['https://www.indiegogo.com/sitemap.xml']`
    `def parse(self, response):`
    `[...]`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code this will crawl the site and only crawl the "indiegogo.com/projects/"

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from sitemap.items import myitem

class DmozSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'indiego'

    allowed_domains = ['indiegogo.com']

        start_urls = [

        'http://indiegogo.com'

    ]

rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=['indiegogo.com/projects/']), callback='parse_items', follow= True),)

        def parse_items(self, response):

        item = myitem()

        item['link'] = response.request.url

        item['title'] = response.xpath('//title').extract()

        yield item
```

Comment: This stops on the first page, returning 0 results. My guess is that it has something to do with the `allow_domains` parameter to the `LinkExtractor`. Can you explain the thought process behind how this code would solve my issue?

Comment: Yes, Does the home page even have a link starting with "indiegogo.com/projects/"

Comment: Ah, no, they're all relative links. I switched it to allow=['/projects/'] but then it only got the 12 projects listed on the home page.